# Finding if the system is little endian or big endian with perl

Tags: perl, endianness

Is there an option to find if my system is little endian byte order or big endian byte order using Perl?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
perl -MConfig -e 'print "$Config{byteorder}\n";'
```

See [Perl documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/Config.html#byacc).

If the first byte of the output string is 1, you can assume (with moderate safety) that it is little-endian. If it is 4 or 8, you can assume big-endian.

Comment: +1 This is clearly the "right" way to do it. The other way is (while intuitive) just hacky. :-P

Comment: True, although to get a boolean answer to the question "is this system big/little-endian?" you'd need to do further analysis on the value returned by the Config module.

Comment: @Sean: the trouble is (as the referenced documentation points out), the answer isn't binary - there is also 'weird' order (in theory) for machines like PDP-11 which use '3412' as the byte order - which is neither big-endian nor little-endian.   If the first byte is 1, you can assume (with moderate safety) that it is little endian; if it is 4 or 8, you can assume big endian; and if it is none of these, then maybe it is time to get a newer machine.

Answer (score 4):

I guess you could do:

```
$big_endian = pack("L", 1) eq pack("N", 1);
```

This might fail if your system has a nonstandard (neither big-endian nor little-endian) byte ordering (eg PDP-11).

Comment: That was going to be my suggestion as well. :) Except I would use something with more bits filled than just binary 1.