# How to check whether a system is big endian or little endian?

Tags: endianness

How to check whether a system is big endian or little endian?

Comment: C: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100331/c-macro-definition-to-determine-big-endian-or-little-endian-machine C++ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001307/detecting-endianness-programmatically-in-a-c-program Shell: https://serverfault.com/questions/163487/how-to-tell-if-a-linux-system-is-big-endian-or-little-endian

Answer (score 119, accepted):

In C, C++

```cpp
int n = 1;
// little endian if true
if(*(char *)&n == 1) {...}
```

See also: [Perl version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610849/finding-if-the-system-is-little-endian-or-big-endian-with-perl)

Comment: Good answer, but this provides a nice diagram of what's going on: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12792301/803801

Comment: Can you tell me why we can't just use `(char)n == 1` ? Why do we have to get the address, convert it to a `char` pointer and then dereference? Won't this be implicitly done `(char)n` is used?

Comment: @J...S Just using a char cast seems to work fine. I haven't tested it on a big-endian system though.

Comment: Just using a char does not work. As casting to char causes the system to convert from an int to a char. It will always return true. Using a cast to pointer and de-reference places the pointer to the first byte of N and then de-references the first byte.

Comment: A cast isn't a conversion.  If Big Endian, then the first byte of N is a zero - so how does that result in true?

Comment: A cast from `int` to `char` will not work; that will give you the least significant byte. That tells you nothing about which end the least significant byte came from.

Comment: The OS/360 programmer who gave me this code > 25 years ago said it works because it's not casting from `int` to `char`, but rather casting address of int to address of char.  @GarretGang comment above explains it.

Comment: I just wrote a bit about this and offered an example in Go with diagrams and such: https://pcolladosoto.github.io/2022/04/26/checking-endianness.html. Hope somebody finds it useful!

Answer (score 75):

In Python:

```py
from sys import byteorder
print(byteorder)
# will print 'little' if little endian
```

Answer (score 18):

Another C code using union

```
union {
    int i;
    char c[sizeof(int)];
} x;
x.i = 1;
if(x.c[0] == 1)
    printf("little-endian\n");
else    printf("big-endian\n");
```

It is same logic that belwood used.

Comment: i think this is not standard compliant though: you may only read the field from an enum that you last have written to otherwise undefined behavior is possible, or am i mistaken?

Comment: unions does not specify "justifying" in standard. This is not correct solution (it may work accidentally in specific OS/compiller).

Comment: Can some please explain the logic in the above program. If initialising the member variable i, with x.1=1, then how x.c[0] is turning out to be 1. Am I missing some point here? my understanding is that union take the memory of the largest data type and depending upon that we can access it. Only one member can be accessed. Any response will be highly appreaciated

Comment: @VivekSingh as you said union take the memory of the largest data type and depending upon that we can access it. So the memory will be same for both the data types. So we are accessing as int and assigning it as 1. So in 4 byte only 1 byte part will have single 1. When we access as char it takes only 1 byte.

Answer (score 17):

In C++20 use [`std::endian`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/endian):

```
#include <bit>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    if constexpr (std::endian::native == std::endian::little)
        std::cout << "little-endian";
    else if constexpr (std::endian::native == std::endian::big)
        std::cout << "big-endian";
    else
        std::cout << "mixed-endian";
}
```

Answer (score 15):

A one-liner with Perl (which should be installed by default on almost all systems):

```
perl -e 'use Config; print $Config{byteorder}'
```

If the output starts with a 1 (least-significant byte), it's a little-endian system. If the output starts with a higher digit (most-significant byte), it's a big-endian system. See documentation of the [Config](https://perldoc.perl.org/Config.html#b) module.

Answer (score 12):

If you are using .NET: Check the value of `BitConverter.IsLittleEndian`.

Answer (score 9):

In Rust (no crates or `use` statements required)

In a function body:

```
if cfg!(target_endian = "big") {
    println!("Big endian");
} else {
    println!("Little endian");
}
```

Outside a function body:

```
#[cfg(target_endian = "big")]
fn print_endian() {
    println!("Big endian")
}

#[cfg(target_endian = "little")]
fn print_endian() {
    println!("Little endian")
}
```

This is what the `byteorder` crate does internally: https://docs.rs/byteorder/1.3.2/src/byteorder/lib.rs.html#1877

Answer (score 7):

In Powershell

```
[System.BitConverter]::IsLittleEndian
```

Answer (score 4):

In Linux,

```c
static union { char c[4]; unsigned long mylong; } endian_test = { { 'l', '?', '?', 'b' } };
#define ENDIANNESS ((char)endian_test.mylong)

if (ENDIANNESS == 'l') /* little endian */
if (ENDIANNESS == 'b') /* big endian */
```

Comment: how is it different from Neeraj's version?

Answer (score 3):

A C++ solution:

```cpp
namespace sys {

const unsigned one = 1U;

inline bool little_endian()
{
    return reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&one) + sizeof(unsigned) - 1;
}

inline bool big_endian()
{
    return !little_endian();
}

} // sys

int main()
{
    if(sys::little_endian())
        std::cout << "little";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In Rust (byteorder crate required):

```
use std::any::TypeId;

let is_little_endian = TypeId::of::<byteorder::NativeEndian>() == TypeId::of::<byteorder::LittleEndian>();
```

Comment: You don't need a crate now: #[cfg(target_endian = "little")] or if cfg!((target_endian = "little") will work.

Answer (score 3):

In case if you want to check it on a linux machine you can use below mentioned cmd

```
lscpu | grep "Byte Order"
```

After running this cmd you will get the output like mentioned below

```
Byte Order:            Little Endian
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Keep in mind that output from `lscpu` could be localized. So `Byte Order` could be translated to your local language.

Answer (score 2):

Using Macro,

```
const int isBigEnd=1;
#define is_bigendian() ((*(char*)&isBigEnd) == 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

In C

```
#include <stdio.h> 

/* function to show bytes in memory, from location start to start+n*/
void show_mem_rep(char *start, int n) 
 { 
      int i; 
      for (i = 0; i < n; i++) 
      printf("%2x ", start[i]); 
      printf("\n"); 
 } 

/*Main function to call above function for 0x01234567*/
int main() 
{ 
   int i = 0x01234567; 
   show_mem_rep((char *)&i, sizeof(i));  
   return 0; 
}
```

When above program is run on little endian machine, gives “67 45 23 01” as output , while if it is run on big endian machine, gives “01 23 45 67” as output.

Comment: Hey, man, It is not your own code, you just copy and paste. You should at least note the source of the code.

Answer (score 2):

A compilable version of the top answer for n00bs:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n = 1;

    // little endian if true
    if(*(char *)&n == 1) {
        printf("Little endian\n");
    } else {
        printf("Big endian\n");
    }   
}
```

Stick that in `check-endianness.c` and compile and run:

```
$ gcc -o check-endianness check-endianness.c
$ ./check-endianness
```

This whole command is a copy/pasteable bash script you can paste into your terminal:

```
cat << EOF > check-endianness.c
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int n = 1;
    // little endian if true
    if(*(char *)&n == 1) {
        printf("Little endian\n");
    } else {
        printf("Big endian\n");
    }   
}
EOF

gcc -o check-endianness check-endianness.c \
 && ./check-endianness \
 && rm check-endianness check-endianness.c
```

The code is [in a gist here](https://gist.github.com/FreedomBen/a12206b1e0609528af65762131c518b6) if you prefer.  There is also [a bash command that you can run that will generate, compile, and clean up after itself](https://gist.github.com/FreedomBen/38b05f1ad113406ea2c87c02c402d3cb).

Answer (score 1):

In [`Nim`](https://nim-lang.org/),

```
echo cpuEndian
```

---

It is exported from the [`system`](https://nim-lang.org/docs/system.html) module.

Answer (score 1):

In bash (from [How to tell if a Linux system is big endian or little endian?](https://serverfault.com/a/163493/943105)):

```
endian=`echo -n "I" | od -to2 | head -n1 | cut -f2 -d" " | cut -c6`

if [ "$endian" == "1" ]; then
  echo "little-endian"
else
  echo "big-endian"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

C logic to check whether your processor follows little endian or big endian

```
unsigned int i =12345; 
char *c = (char *)&i; // typecast int to char* so that it points to first bit of int
if(*c != 0){          // If *c points to 0 then it is Big endian else Little endian
printf("Little endian");
}
else{
printf("Big endian");
}
```

Hope this helps. Was one of the question asked in my interview for the role of embedded software engineer role

Comment: This is pretty similar in approach to the top answer and actually the same approach has been shown multiple times already. I don't see how this answer adds anything to what is already here.

Answer (score 1):

in C with GCC 9.4:

```
#include <endian.h>

#if __BYTE_ORDER == __LITTLE_ENDIAN
...
#endif
```

N.B. trap for the unwary : *DON'T* do this:

```
#ifdef __LITTLE_ENDIAN
```

because both __LITTLE_ENDIAN and __BIG_ENDIAN are defined in endian.h! Also LITTLE_ENDIAN / BIG_ENDIAN (no leading underscores are defined)

Answer (score 0):

In Java:

```
import java.nio.ByteOrder;

public class EndiannessCheck {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ByteOrder byteOrder = ByteOrder.nativeOrder();
        if (byteOrder.equals(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN)) {
            System.out.println("Little Endian");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Big Endian");
        }
    }
}
```