# big endian or little endian?

Tags: objective-c, c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to check whether a system is big endian or little endian?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181951/how-to-check-whether-a-system-is-big-endian-or-little-endian)

how to know whether the machine am using is big or little endian? Is there a code i can write to do that?

Comment: Numerous duplicates, e.g. [How to check whether a system is big endian or little endian?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181951/how-to-check-whether-a-system-is-big-endian-or-little-endian) and [Detecting endianness programmatically in a C++ program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001307/detecting-endianness-programmatically-in-a-c-program)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following code should get you the answer.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  long x = 0x44434241;
  char *y = (char *) &x;

  if(strncmp(y,"ABCD",4)){
   printf("Big Endian\n");
  }else{
   printf("little Endian\n");
  }
}
```

Explanation

In `little endian` 4 bytes are stored as `[4th, 3rd , 2nd, 1st]`. `0x41` is `A` and `0x42` is `B`and so. This bytestrem is interpreted as character string and using `strncpy` we determine how bytes are actually arranged in machine and decide is its `little or big endian`.

Comment: While it surely works, it has the disadvantage of using a function call. Simply dereferencing the char pointer and thus looking at the first "character" is enough.

Comment: This example is even better and simpler to understand than the wikipedia article. I've read the one so many times, but these few lines of code summarized basically everything I needed to know.

Answer (score 6):

```
int main()
{
  unsigned int i = 0x12345678; // assuming int is 4 bytes.
  unsigned char* pc = (unsigned char*) &i;

  if (*pc == 0x12)
    printf("Big Endian. i = 0x%x, *pc = 0x%x\n", i, *pc);
  else if (*pc == 0x78)
    printf("Little Endian. i = 0x%x, *pc = 0x%x\n", i, *pc);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1 Seems like this would be faster than the accepted answer.

Comment: prepend `&i` in line four with the explicit type cast `(unsigned char*)` to get rid of gcc's compile warning (-Wint-conversion).