# How to tell an Openwrt Build target is using big endian or little endian?

Tags: linux, mips, embed, openwrt

[MIPS](https://www.linux-mips.org/wiki/Endianness): this link says MIPS can be configured to use big or little endian.
I build a target of ar71xx-mikrotik in Openwrt. How can I know that my build is big endian or little endian?
Running code on the machine may be one solution: [big endian or little endian?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5432515/big-endian-or-little-endian)
But can I know it by reading the build configuration of Openwrt?

Comment: Compile or assemble some code and look at (disassemble) the binary object file (using objdump or something like it).  I should show you bytes of code and the addresses they're at so you can reason whether big or little endian.

Comment: Seems to be using GCC, so look at https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/MIPS-Options.html...