# Is this code true to know whether system is little endian or big endian?

Tags: c, endianness

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()                                                                                                                              
{
    unsigned int unum = 0x80008001;
    short unsigned int *snum = (short unsigned int*)&unum;
    printf("%d\n", *snum);
    printf("%d\n", *(snum+1));
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
32769
32768
```

snum is pointing to the initial two bytes of the unum, but it's value is last two bytes of unum, and after incrementing pointer, value is the first two byte of unum.

So, It is a little endian system.
But, i am not sure whether this way is right or not to know  the system's type.
Is it proper?

Comment: C++ answer: Or it won't compile, perhaps?

Comment: Obvious strict aliasing violation is obvious.

Comment: @HotLicks: Not how I read it. The first number is the low part, right?

Comment: @MatsPetersson - Yeah, it got me confused.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check whether a system is big endian or little endian?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181951/how-to-check-whether-a-system-is-big-endian-or-little-endian)

Comment: @2501 ,I am asking whether this is the proper way or not, i have also seen the similar questions on SO.

Comment: @jagsgediya: Given that as C++ it doesn't compile at all, and as C will give you warnings, I'd say that's not a good sign. Don't you think?

Comment: @MatsPetersson **gcc code.c -Wall -Werror**, not showing any error or warnings.

Comment: Ah, because you fixed the missing cast. I would still prefer to use a `char` than an `unsigned short`, simply because it will ensure that you don't break strict aliasing rules.

Comment: Which standard are you reading, and where. AS Loopunroller says, the C standard forbids casting a pointer to another type. You could use `memcpy` or use `char` or `unsigned char`, since those are allowed to be cast to/from by the language.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code induces undefined behavior as you violate the strict aliasing rule (§6.5/7 for the C standard, [basic.lval]/10 for C++). The code accesses the stored value of `unum` through an lvalue of a completely different type. With a C++ compiler the above code won't even compile since implicit casts between unrelated pointer types are forbidden.

Use `char` or `unsigned char` aliases to access single bytes from an object representation, those  types are excluded from the strict aliasing rule. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181951/how-to-check-whether-a-system-is-big-endian-or-little-endian) are examples.

Answer (score 1):

For me the code you've submitted does not compile, thus I would assume you cannot do this trick. However [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1001373/2604672) shows how to solve the problem you're talking about.

My compiler:

```
Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
```

Comment: For me, code is compiling fine on ubuntu 12.04 with gcc version 4.6.3.

Comment: @jagsgediya: Then you should enable compiler warnings (`-Wall`).

Comment: Code is updated, and now it is not showing any warnings even.