# How do I convert this hex value in a u32_t to its corresponding char/ascii value?

Tags: c, embedded

I'm trying to read data from a TCP stack and using the data to control external interfaces etc. The data is in u32_t so if I write for example "test" to the interface the hex value corresponds to 0x74657374. I want to convert this data to their corresponding characters so it is easier to use the data. How do I convert hexadecimal values in a u32_t to its char string?

I've tried print the data directly via the %c format specifier but then it only shows the first character of the string.

```
/* indicate that the packet has been received */
tcp_recved(tpcb, p->len);
// Put actual data in 32 bit unsigned integer.
tempPtr = (u32_t*)p->payload;
// Print length of the actual data.
xil_printf("Received package. Length = %d \r\n", p->len);
// Reverse the data so it corresponds to the data sent.
u32_t reversedTemp = byte_reverse_32(*tempPtr);

// Prints hex value of data
xil_printf("Data: %08x \r\n",reversedTemp);

if (reversedTemp == 0x6C656431) { /* Read "led1" */
    xil_printf("Data Read: led1");
} else if (reversedTemp == 0x74657374) { /* Read "test */
    xil_printf("Data Read: test");
}
```

So where I'm using the full hex value in the if statement I only want to use the string value. So for checking test it should be == "test" instead of == 0x74657374.

Comment: You can't use `==` to compare strings in C anyway, you need to use [`strcmp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp) to compare ***null-terminated*** byte strings.

Comment: For effectiveness, what you have now is pretty optimal. What I recommend is that you stop using [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)) and replace them with symbolic constants (basically preprocessor macros), but otherwise keep the current comparison (then you don't even have to do the reversion step, to save a few CPU cycles, and the code would still make sense). Oh, and you don't really need the pointer, instead do e.g. `u32_t temp = *(u32_t*)p->payload`.

Comment: And finally, if you still want to compare using ASCII strings, you could use [`memcmp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memcmp) and not have to bother about null-termination.

Comment: I am note sure but doesn't he mean 0x74657374 should equal to the characters t,e,s and t, respectively? And not being an address of to a char array.

Comment: The fact that it's not an address to a char array doesn't matter since C isn't very type-safe. You can cast values between types willy-nilly and the compiler won't complain at all. Because of this you can create a variable: `u32_t led1 = 0x6C656431;`; then gets its address and cast it to a "pointer to a char array": `(char*)led1`; and it would technically be roughly equivalent to "led1".

Comment: Yea sure with the declaration of the address of led1 as a char* I agree!

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Strict aliasing!?

Comment: There is no "hex value", it is just an _integer_.  The hex is is just a representation of the integer.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to get the address of the variable then cast that to a `char*`.

```c
if (memcmp("test", tempPtr), 4) {
    // The input was "test"
}
```

You might run into issues related to [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness). [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4181991/4149561) has a soltion to that.

Comment: There is a problem if the data pointed to by `tempPtr` is not *null-terminated*. `memcmp` could be used instead.

Comment: Oops, that's why I used strncmp but I forgot the last argument. Good point about memcmp though.

Answer (score 0):

You have a bug here: `tempPtr = (u32_t*)p->payload;` ... `byte_reverse_32(*tempPtr)`. This is a strict aliasing violation and quite likely also a misaligned access. Don't do this.

There's no apparent need to swap the bytes around to compensate for endianess since you intend to convert them to a string anyway(?). If so, you can do this instead (assuming network big endian, CPU little endian):

```
tcp_recved(tpcb, p->len);
char str[4+1] =
{
  [0] = p->payload[3];
  [1] = p->payload[2];
  [2] = p->payload[1];
  [3] = p->payload[0];
  [4] = '\0'
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Given :

```
uint32_t num = 0x74657374 ;
```

Then:

```
char str[5] = {0} ;
str[0] = num >> 24 ;
str[1] = (num >> 16) & 0xff ;
str[2] = (num >> 8) & 0xff ;
str[3] = num & 0xff ;
```

The byte reversal may be unnecessary, you can simply reverse the unpacking to get the string in one step when the first character is in the LSB:

```
char str[5] = {0} ;
str[0] = num & 0xff ;
str[1] = (num >> 8) & 0xff ;
str[2] = (num >> 16) & 0xff ;
str[3] = num >> 24 ;
```

For the specific cases of either:

- a big-endian target and the first character in the MSB, or
- a little-endian target and the first character in the LSB,

then just:

```
char str[5] = {0} ;
memcpy( str, &num, 4 ) ;
```

All that said in this case your existing solution is more efficient than string or memory compare.  But again the byte reversal is unnecessary - just reverse the byte order in the integer, and avoid the "magic numbers":

```
#define TEST 0x74736574u ;  // "tset" ("test" reversed)

...

uint32_t temp = *((u32_t*)p->payload) ;
if( temp == TEST ) ...
```

The string conversion perhaps remains useful is you want to output the strings for debug or human presentation.