# Bitwise operations and endianness in C program

Tags: c, sdl, endianness

I am having trouble trying to understand how exactly is my computer doing bitwise operations depending on endianness.
I've read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181951/how-to-check-whether-a-system-is-big-endian-or-little-endian) and [this article](http://bruceblinn.com/linuxinfo/ByteOrder.html) and I think I have confirmed my machine works in little endian (I have tried several programs described in both sources and all of them seem to output my machine is indeed little endian).
I have the following macros defined that use SDL and swap 2 and 4 byte values in case needed:

```
#if SDL_BYTEORDER == SDL_BIG_ENDIAN

#define HTON16(n) (n)
#define NTOH16(n) (n)
#define HTON32(n) (n)
#define NTOH32(n) (n)
#define HTON64(n) (n)
#define NTOH64(n) (n)
#else
    
#define HTON16(n) SDL_Swap16(n)
#define NTOH16(n) SDL_Swap16(n)
#define HTON32(n) SDL_Swap32(n)
#define NTOH32(n) SDL_Swap32(n)
#define HTON64(n) SDL_Swap64(n)
#define NTOH64(n) SDL_Swap64(n)
#endif
```

My problem is:
When writing a 2 byte number (in this case 43981 = 0xabcd) to a char[], say, at the entry 0, the following code would produce the first 2 bytes of data in little endian, i.e. 0xcdab, when I'm trying to do the opposite thing:

```
char data[100];
int host_value = 43981; // 0xabcd
int net_value = HTON16(host_value);

data[0] = (net_value & 0xff00) >> 8;
data[1] = (net_value & 0xff);
```

My solution to the previous problem is just not using HTON16 on the host value, and operating with it as if my machine was big endian.
Also, in the same machine, when doing the following to write the same host value to data, it does produce data to have the two first byte set to 0xabcd:

```
*((unsigned short *)&data[0]) = HTON16(host_value);
```

I would like to understand why these two cases work differently. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please [edit] and show a [mcve] along with expected vs. actual output.

Comment: I would need to compile SDL on a sample program reproduce the macros, this is why I did not. But to be more specific, assume theres a function with prototype:
void hexdump(char* data, int len) ; that writes to stdout a buffer's content up to len.
I would like, after doing my procedure, to call this function on data an len=2 and have abcd instead of cdab.

Comment: Please note that considering `data` is `char[]`, then type punning with invalid data type in `*((unsigned short *)&data[0])` is *strict aliasing violation* which leads to *undefined behaviour*. This means that your code will not work reliably unless you set your compiler to non-standard mode. If you don't know what this all means, don't use it. Use `memcpy` instead.

Comment: It is just an example, in the real code theres a pointer and theres its malloc.

Comment: It could be... One thing I have not dig into is checking what does SDL do to check the machine's endianness. Maybe it's doing nothing and as you say it assumes big endian.

Comment: Perhaps your confusion is that you think bitwise operations and shifts have anything to do with endianness

Comment: I thought so, but I guess it does not ? It blows my mind how exactly it does not matter, if you have any reference I could read I would appreciate it.

Comment: Think of 43981 as "just a 16-bit number". You want `data[0]` to contain the most significant 8 bits of that 16-bit number, and one way to do that is `data[0] = (43981 & 0xff00) >> 8;`. Notice the lack of use of the `HTON(n)` macro in this expression.

Comment: Yes it looks like everyone is agreeing that (2bytenum & 0xff00 >> 8) gives the most significant byte on any machine.

Comment: This is not a matter of agreement. :-D It is a matter of fact that in C the expression `(x >> 8) & 0xFF` or `(x & 0xFF00U) >> 8` evaluates to the upper byte of a 2-byte value.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is these two lines,

```
data[0] = (net_value & 0xff00) >> 8;
data[1] = (net_value & 0xff);
```

If you run on a little-endian machine,

- (net_value & 0xff00) is equivalent to getting the second character, you should want the first character
- (net_value & 0xff) is the first character,

if you use bit operations, it should be a direct operation, no need to call HTON16

Comment: Your answer is definately coherent with my problem. I would like, though, to have some references for it, since stating something without documentation backup might get me in trouble. Could you give me a reference ?

Comment: @carce-bo I doubt that any kind of reference can be found, because it's just simple bitwise math. If you do calculations by hand on paper, you should be able to show why code swaps endianness twice.

Comment: You can google the keyword "Big and Little Endian Byte Order"
Such as:  https://betterexplained.com/articles/understanding-big-and-little-endian-byte-order/  or https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/little-and-big-endian-mystery/