# How to get numeric value of a hash?

Tags: hash, blockchain, sha

On the [Proof of work](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Proof_of_work) blockchain wiki, one can find that the hash

```
0000c3af42fc31103f1fdc0151fa747ff87349a4714df7cc52ea464e12dcd4e9
```

corresponds to the value 2^239.61238653. My question is, how can one calculate this numeric value of a hash?

Comment: Convert hexadecimal to decimal and get the base2 logarithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that the block hash is usually represented as a hexadecimal, little [endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) value, when you try to convert to decimal. If [your system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610849/finding-if-the-system-is-little-endian-or-big-endian-with-perl) is little-endian:

To convert to decimal in bash/perl:

```
$ hex=0000c3af42fc31103f1fdc0151fa747ff87349a4714df7cc52ea464e12dcd4e9
$ $ perl -le 'use bignum qw/hex/; print hex("0x".$ARGV[0])' --"$hex"
532607621168989936896605052113495566299419916018780134558135832581308350315356027254565114944
```

or, to get base2 log:

```
perl -le 'use bignum qw/hex/; print log(hex($ARGV[0]))/log(2)' -- "$hex" 
239.6123865298365295145460775449928303015
```

Which represents `2^239.61238653`